# PACKET_MMAP TX_RING Issues on subsequent send() calls

Tags: c, sockets, linux-kernel, mmap, raw-sockets

Thanks for taking the time to look at this. It's an issue I've been dealing with for a week or so now, and I'm dumbfounded. Any input would be great.

I am currently using PACKET_MMAP TX_RING V3 (I've tried V2 and V1, but I have the same problem with them. I've decided to use V3 because I am able to keep multiple eth frames on one block, rather than only being able to have 1 frame per tp_block in V1 & V2) to avoid excessive systems calls in the sending process of my port scanner. I am not setting up an RX_RING, so that is not part of the picture.

Right now I am only testing this with one host and I am only hitting ports 5 ports I know are active.

So... here's the situation:

I have a TX_RING: [1 block | block size 4096 | 32 frames | frame size 128]

code for TX_RING setup:

```
int                     prepare_packetmmap_tx_ring(t_thread *thread)
{
    int                 tpacket_v;
    struct sockaddr_ll  sll_loc;

    /* Step 1 Create PF_PACKET socket.*/
    thread->sock = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
    if (thread->sock == -1)
    {
        toggle_thread_alive(thread);
        return (hermes_error(FAILURE, "socket() %s", strerror(errno)));
    }

    memset(&sll_loc, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));
    memcpy(&sll_loc.sll_addr, thread->pool->iface.if_hwaddr, ETH_ALEN);
    sll_loc.sll_ifindex = thread->pool->iface.inx;
    sll_loc.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
    sll_loc.sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_ALL);
    /* Bind our socket to the interface */
    if (bind(thread->sock, (sockaddr *)&sll_loc, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll)) == -1)
    {
        toggle_thread_alive(thread);
        return (hermes_error(FAILURE, "bind() %s", strerror(errno)));
    }

    tpacket_v = TPACKET_V3;
    if (setsockopt(thread->sock, SOL_PACKET, PACKET_VERSION, &tpacket_v, sizeof(tpacket_v)) < 0)
    {
        toggle_thread_alive(thread);
        return (hermes_error(FAILURE, "setsockopt() PACKET_VERSION %s", strerror(errno)));
    }

    /* Step 3 determine sizes for PACKET_TX_RING and allocate txring via setsockopt() */
    thread->txring.tpr.tp_block_size = (uint)getpagesize();
    thread->txring.tpr.tp_frame_size = TPACKET3_HDRLEN + sizeof(struct ethhdr) + sizeof(struct iphdr) + DEF_TRAN_HDRLEN + thread->pool->env->cpayload_len;
    thread->txring.tpr.tp_frame_size = pow2_round(thread->txring.tpr.tp_frame_size);
    thread->txring.tpr.tp_block_nr = (THRD_HSTGRP_MAX / (thread->txring.tpr.tp_block_size / thread->txring.tpr.tp_frame_size));
    thread->txring.tpr.tp_frame_nr = thread->txring.tpr.tp_block_nr * (thread->txring.tpr.tp_block_size / thread->txring.tpr.tp_frame_size);
    thread->txring.size = thread->txring.tpr.tp_block_size * thread->txring.tpr.tp_block_nr;
    thread->txring.doffset = sizeof(struct tpacket3_hdr);

    if (setsockopt(thread->sock, SOL_PACKET, PACKET_TX_RING, (void *)&thread->txring.tpr, sizeof(thread->txring.tpr)) < 0)
    {
        toggle_thread_alive(thread);
        return (hermes_error(FAILURE, "setsockopt() PACKET_TX_RING %s", strerror(errno)));
    }

    printf("frame size: %d | blocksize: %d | block count %d | frame count %d\n", thread->txring.tpr.tp_frame_size, thread->txring.tpr.tp_block_size, thread->txring.tpr.tp_block_nr, thread->txring.tpr.tp_frame_nr);
    extra_sock_opts(thread->sock, thread->txring.size);
    /* Step 4 actually map ring to user space */
    if (!(thread->txring.ring = mmap(0, thread->txring.size,
            PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
            MAP_SHARED,
            thread->sock, 0)))
    {
        toggle_thread_alive(thread);
        return (hermes_error(FAILURE, "mmap() TX_RING %s", strerror(errno)));
    }
    return (SUCCESS);
}
```

So... all fine and dandy right? Let's move on to my ring fill process:

```
        nt                      fill_tx_ring(t_thread *thread, t_frame *ethframe)
{
    struct tpacket3_hdr *frame;
    void                *data;
    uint16_t            *srcports;
    uint16_t            *dstports;
    uint                ring_i;
    uint                hst_i;
    int                 ret;

    ring_i = 0;
    hst_i = 0;
    ret = 0;
    srcports = thread->pool->env->ports.flat;
    dstports = thread->pool->env->dstports;
    while (hst_i < thread->hstgrpsz && ring_i < thread->txring.tpr.tp_frame_nr)
    {
        if (thread->hstgrp[hst_i].health.done == true)
        {
            hst_i++;
            continue;
        }
        frame = (struct tpacket3_hdr *)(thread->txring.ring + (thread->txring.tpr.tp_frame_size * ring_i));
        switch((volatile uint32_t)frame->tp_status)
        {
            case TP_STATUS_WRONG_FORMAT:
                return(hermes_error(FAILURE, "TX_RING wrong format in frame %i of thread %d", ring_i, thread->id));
            case TP_STATUS_AVAILABLE:
                data = (uint8_t *)frame + thread->txring.doffset;
                ethframe->ip->daddr = thread->hstgrp[hst_i].result->ip.s_addr;
                ip_checksum(ethframe->ip);
                ethframe->tcp->source = htons(dstports[thread->hstgrp[hst_i].health.portinx]);
                ethframe->tcp->dest = htons(srcports[thread->hstgrp[hst_i].health.portinx]);
                tcp_checksum(ethframe->ip, (uint16_t *)ethframe->tcp);
                memcpy(data, ethframe->buffer, ethframe->size);
                frame->tp_next_offset = 0;
                frame->tp_len = ethframe->size;
                frame->tp_status = TP_STATUS_SEND_REQUEST;
                printf("setup a frame\n");
                ret++; hst_i++; ring_i++;
                break;
            default:
                printf("skipped ring with status %d\n", frame->tp_status);
                ring_i++;
                break;
        }
    }
    return (ret);
}
```

(edit/note: Ive also tried polling POLL_OUT on my socket until tp_status changes on a frame, this yeilds the same result.)

So this filling process will fill up one frame because I am only scanning one host, and I only send one message to a host at a time.
The first send works great! It sends the frame, I see it on Wireshark, I get the response, I process it, then we get back to the fill_tx_ring() routine. Below is my scan function so you can see the order in which this is happening:

```
void                    syn_scan(t_thread *thread)
{
    struct timeval      sent = {0};
    struct timeval      now = {0};
    long ms;
    int                 ret;
    t_frame             frame;

    memset(&frame, 0, sizeof(t_frame));
    init_ethframe(thread, &frame);
    thread->scancnt = thread->hstgrpsz;
    while (thread->scancnt > 0)
    {
        gettimeofday(&now, NULL);
        if ((ms = timediff_ms(&now, &sent)) >= DEF_INIT_RTT_TIMEOUT)
        {
            fill_tx_ring(thread, &frame);
            send_task(thread);
            gettimeofday(&sent, NULL);
            thread->rxfilter.fd.events = POLL_IN;
            if ((ret = poll(&thread->rxfilter.fd, 1, 
DEF_INIT_RTT_TIMEOUT)) < 0)
                hermes_error(FAILURE, "poll() %s", strerror(errno));
            if (ret > 0)
                pcap_dispatch(thread->rxfilter.handle,
                              thread->hstgrpsz, handle_packet, 
(u_char*)thread);
            else
                printf("didn't get anything\n");
        }
        else
        {
            usleep((useconds_t) ms * 1000);
        }

    }
    free(frame.buffer);
    frame.buffer = NULL;
}
```

Now the real issue: every other call to send() returns 0. On subsequent calls to fill_tx_ring(), I find that all of the frames I have filled previously are not being updated by the kernel (due to the failed send(), it seems like the kernel never even receives the request or looks at the ring)... their tp_status fields are still set to TP_STATUS_SEND_REQUEST.

Even after we have a successful send() (let's say the third successful) you'll notice that the frames which have already been used to transmit a frame are all still set to 1 (TP_STATUS_SEND_REQUEST).

A logged output from my program looks like this:

```
index 2 | mac: a8:7d:12:1:b6:46:| ip: 10.43.1.162 | gwip: 10.43.1.254 
| gwmac: 0:35:1a:54:ca:17:
frame size: 128 | blocksize: 4096 | block count 1 | frame count 32
ports total 5

setup a frame
sent 1 packets
packet processed
a8  7d 12 01 b6 46 00 35 
1a 54 ca 17 08 00 45  00 00 2c 00 00 40 00 
3f 06 1f 7c 0a 72 06  12 0a 2b 01 a2 16 00 
b1 f8 52 03 f6 a0 00  00 00 02 60 12 ff ff 
81 11 00 00 02 04 05  b4 00 00 

setup a frame
didn't send anything.
didn't get anything

skipped ring with status 1
setup a frame
sent 1 packets
packet processed
a8  7d 12 01 b6 46 00 35 
1a 54 ca 17 08 00 45  00 00 2c 00 00 40 00 
3f 06 1f 7c 0a 72 06  12 0a 2b 01 a2 58 00 
ac ac 06 32 5f 44 00  00 00 02 60 12 ff ff 
69 49 00 00 02 04 05  b4 00 00 

skipped ring with status 1
setup a frame
didn't send anything.
didn't get anything

skipped ring with status 1
skipped ring with status 1
setup a frame
sent 1 packets
packet processed
a8  7d 12 01 b6 46 00 35 
1a 54 ca 17 08 00 45  00 00 2c 00 00 40 00 
3f 06 1f 7c 0a 72 06  12 0a 2b 01 a2 d3 0c 
e7 f1 14 3c 13 c4 00  00 00 02 60 12 ff ff 
5e ff 00 00 02 04 05  b4 00 00 

skipped ring with status 1
skipped ring with status 1
setup a frame
didn't send anything.
didn't get anything

skipped ring with status 1
skipped ring with status 1
skipped ring with status 1
setup a frame
sent 1 packets
packet processed
a8  7d 12 01 b6 46 00 35 
1a 54 ca 17 08 00 45  00 00 2c 00 00 40 00 
3f 06 1f 7c 0a 72 06  12 0a 2b 01 a2 ea 0c 
8a 10 f0 d0 aa 9b 00  00 00 02 60 12 ff ff 
49 5d 00 00 02 04 05  b4 00 00 

skipped ring with status 1
skipped ring with status 1
skipped ring with status 1
setup a frame
didn't send anything.
didn't get anything
ms 1000
skipped ring with status 1
skipped ring with status 1
skipped ring with status 1
skipped ring with status 1
setup a frame
sent 1 packets
packet processed
a8  7d 12 01 b6 46 00 35 
1a 54 ca 17 08 00 45  00 00 2c 00 00 40 00 
3f 06 1f 7c 0a 72 06  12 0a 2b 01 a2 0c 17 
ee 5f a7 98 89 b2 00  00 00 02 60 12 ff ff 
45 0d 00 00 02 04 05  b4 00 00 
thread 1 closing 0 still alive
```

So why is the kernel not giving me my frames back, and why does every other call to send() fail to send the frame I've set in the ring?

Much appreciation in advance!

You can see the full code:

project:
https://github.com/dauie/hermes.git

tx setup:
https://github.com/Dauie/hermes/blob/master/src/thread.c

tx_fill/send:
https://github.com/Dauie/hermes/blob/master/src/scan.c

Comment: Nevermind. I didn't fix it. Wishful thinking...

Comment: So I've found that If I completely fill up the TX ring and send, everything goes well, or If I just make the TX ring composed of 1 block and 1 frame, it works fine. This being said I could allocate a new ring buffer each time I enter my scan, but this sounds very expensive. I want to be able to allocate my ring once, and use it initially for small batches of packets, then when my program has ramped up, I can utilize the entire ring. Still trying to figure out how to use my (currently oversized) ring for packet "bursts" smaller than the ring's frame count.